# why does it say "The attribute name is undefined for the annotation type Parameterized.Parameters"

Tags: junit, openssl, parameterized-tests

I have written a code as follow:
but while compiling it throws the compilation error saying

> "The attribute 'name' is undefined for the annotation type
>   Parameterized.Parameters"

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TrustStandaloneTestSimple {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
    }

    @Parameters(name = "propertyFileName")
    public static Collection<String[]> getParameters(){ 

        return Arrays.asList(new String [][]{{"trust.keystore.simple1.properties"},
                                            {"trust.keystore.simple2.properties"}});
    }
```

Comment: what are your imports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different imports other than below may cause the issue

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
```

Please check your imports

Comment: Already imported everything correctly. It was just the configuration issue that caused this error. System was using older version of JUnit. Nothing wrong in declaration. Thanks for the help though.